# Фильтрация пользовательского PHP-кода

Tags: php, безопасность, защита, шаблонизаторы

Здравствуйте.
По некоторым причинам мне надо, чтобы пользователи имели возможность посылать на мой сервер форму с произвольным PHP-кодом, дабы этот код выполнился на сервере. Возможно ли как-то фильтровать небезопасные для сервера скрипты? К примеру, запретить все функции и конструкции, кроме "foreach", "echo", "if($var1==$var2)" и т.д.?
Или, возможно, существуют некие простейшие шаблонизаторы, с помощью которых от пользователя можно было бы принимать не PHP-код, а HTML-шаблон, и выполнять его?
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Конечно существуют. Есть сайты позволяющие запускать код онлайн. Это называется phpsandbox. Забейте в гугл phpsandbox+github, чтобы найти именно варианты написанные на php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Безопасно выполнять код можно разными способами:

1. с помощью библиотеки https://github.com/Corveda/PHPSandbox
2. с поиощью расширения http://php.net/manual/ru/book.runkit.php
3. настроив дополнительный сервер или выполняя скрипты в отдельном процессе

Но вам, скорее всего, достаточно будет шаблонизатора. Их тысячи. Один из самых популярных - [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). Вы можете сами контролировать компиляцию шаблона, показывая пользователю ошибки. Вызываете `$twig->parse($twig->tokenize($template));` и ловите исключения.